Keycloak throws "JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature" when verifying with Express
I am using Keycloak and want to verify the users token before allowing them to access the server.
For this, I am using the following middlware:
require('dotenv').config();
import axios from "axios";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';

async function getKeycloakPublicKey(): Promise<string> {
  try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/certs`);
      const key = response.data.keys[0].x5c[0];
      return `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${key}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n`;
  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Server | getKeycloakPublicKey | Error: ", error)
      throw new Error('Server | getKeycloakPublicKey | Unable to fetch Keycloak public key');
  }
}

async function verifyToken(token: string) {
  try {
      const publicKey = await getKeycloakPublicKey();
      console.log(token, publicKey)
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, publicKey);
      return decodedToken;
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Server | verifyToken | Token verification failed:', error);
      throw new Error('Token verification failed');
  }
}

const checkToken = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    try {
      await verifyToken(token);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json({ message: "Access Denied: Invalid Token" });
    }
  } else {
    console.log("server | checkToken | No token found");
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Access Denied: No Token Provided" });
  }
}

However, it is throwing an invalid JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature error when it attempts to verify the my token:

Server | verifyToken | Token verification failed: JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature

My public key is in the correct format, and the token is valid because I pull it directly from the keycloak client:
const client = new Keycloak({
   url: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_URL,
   realm: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
   clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID
})

export const useAuth = (setToken: (token: string | undefined) => any) => {
   const hasLoginOccurred = useRef(false)
   const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(false)
   useEffect(() => {
      if (!hasLoginOccurred.current) {
         client.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then((res) => {
            if (res && client.token) {
               console.log('useAuth | useEffect | User has logged in: ' + res);
               setToken(client.token);
               hasLoginOccurred.current = true;
               setLogin(true)
            } else {
               console.error('useAuth | useEffect | User has not logged in: ' + res);
            }
         }).catch((error) => console.error('useAuth | useEffect | Login error: ', error));
      }
   }, [])
   return isLogin;
}

Why is it throwing an error?
